# Change Whole Application Language based on Spinner Selected Value

Tags: android, localization

In my application, I have numbers of Activity Classes and I want to change entire Application Language Based on Spinner Value Selected. Please help me. I am able to change single activity language by following code.

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {

            if (pos == 1) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected Tamil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("ta");
            } else if (pos == 2) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected Hindi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("hi");
            } else if (pos == 3) {

                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                        "You have selected English", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                setLocale("en");
            }

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });
}

public void setLocale(String lang) {

    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
    Intent refresh = new Intent(this, ActivityLanguage.class);
    startActivity(refresh);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("your spinner selection code");
```

**// Locale locale = new Locale("ru"); for example.**

```
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
      getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Thnxx CodingRat.. let me ask you. it will change entire Application Language of only currently opens Activity ??

Comment: create a base activity for all your activity then it will change for all but still you need to take care configuration changes. or you can do it application level.

Comment: How to achieve this goal dear.. I am still in confusion. How to implement application as you explained me in your previous comment ? please give me any source code or link which explains everything..